# Creating new table in SQLite when the system date changes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been trying to make an `SQLite` database which creates a new table every year automatically with the name along the lines of `abc_2018`. The problem is that every time a new table has to be added (**i.e. the year changes**) I need to update the `DATABASE_VERSION`. This probably requires storage of the current `DATABASE_VERSION` and incrementing its value every time a new table has to be added. I tried using `SharedPreferences` but I keep getting random errors.

So my question is how do I make a mechanism that automatically creates a table when the user's system date changes, or more precisely, when a new year starts?

**EDIT**

<strike>Solved my problem by doing this:</strike>

```
try {
  cur = db.query(TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION, SELECTION, ARGS, null, null, null);
 } catch (SQLiteException e) {
   if (e.getMessage().contains("no such table")){
     // create new table and execute query
  }
}
```

Comment: the question is imho: why would you want to create a new table for every year? if you **really** need it just call `SQLiteDatabase#execSQL`

Comment: why dont you want to add additional `year` column?

Comment: i was concerned about the table size getting too big which would lead to performance issues (although im not too sure how many entries would make it "too big")

Comment: ok so how many rows do you expect per year? 1000? 100,000? more?

Comment: less than 100,000 for sure but could go over 1000...

Comment: also, i was so focused on using a DBhelper with the on upgrade method that i forgot i could just execSQL in a try catch block in my fragment... so I implemented that and looks like my problem has been solved. So thank you for that suggestion. I'd still love to know how many rows makes a table "too big" though.

Comment: first try to [create index](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/) with your `year` column + some other column(s), it for sure will work just fine

Comment: `if (e.getMessage().contains("no such table"))` no no no, its so ugly workaround that i dont know what to say... what if they change it to `"No such table"` someday? or `"that table does not exist"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :-

```
try {
  cur = db.query(TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION, SELECTION, ARGS, null, null, null);
 } catch (SQLiteException e) {
   if (e.getMessage().contains("no such table")){
     // create new table and execute query
  }
}
```

Regarding the potential issues as pointed out by pskink's comment:-

> `if (e.getMessage().contains("no such table"))` no no no, its so ugly
>   workaround that i dont know what to say... what if they change it to
>   `"No such table"` someday? or `"that table does not exist"`?

The following would be more resilient (considering how SQLite caters for backwards compatibility) :-

```
cur = db.query(sqlite_master,new String{"tbl_name"},"tbl_name=?",new String[]{TABLE_NAME},null,null,null);
if (cur.getCount < 1) { // ==0 if you prefer
    //Create new table
}
```

Comment: much, much better, but still, i think that creating a separate table for each year is a 
violation of the rules (and common sense as well)

Comment: Yeah I kinda thought it wasn't the prettiest way. Thanks for the help. I'd like to know why pskink thinks creating a table each year is a violation of rules though

Comment: @anshenguin would you like to have a column that stores all the streets of Jalandhar city, another column that stores all the streets of Bangalore city, another column that stores streets of Delhi, another column that stores .... and yet another column and ... or rather one column for street name and the other that keeps city id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver like ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

More details can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

Code:

```
public void createDynamicDatabase(Context context,String tableName,ArrayList<String> title) {

                Log.i("INSIDE createLoginDatabase() Method","*************creatLoginDatabase*********");
                try {

                    int i;
                    String queryString;
                    myDataBase = context.openOrCreateDatabase("Db",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);         //Opens database in writable mode.
                    //System.out.println("Table Name : "+tableName.get(0));

                    queryString = title.get(0)+" VARCHAR(30),";
                    Log.d("**createDynamicDatabase", "in oncreate");

                    for(i = 1; i < title.size() - 1; i++)
                    {               
                        queryString += title.get(i);
                        queryString +=" VARCHAR(30)";
                        queryString +=",";
                    }

                    queryString+= title.get(i) +" VARCHAR(30)";

                    queryString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "("+queryString+");";

                    System.out.println("Create Table Stmt : "+ queryString);

                    myDataBase.execSQL(queryString);

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Log.i("CreateDB Exception ",ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

            public void insert(Context context,ArrayList<String> array_vals,ArrayList<String> title,String TABLE_NAME) {
                Log.d("Inside Insert","Insertion starts for table name: "+TABLE_NAME);
                myDataBase = context.openOrCreateDatabase("Db",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);         //Opens database in writable mode.
                String titleString=null;
                String markString= null;
                int i;
                titleString = title.get(0)+",";
                markString = "?,";

                Log.d("**createDynamicDatabase", "in oncreate");

                for(i = 1; i < title.size() - 1; i++)
                {               
                    titleString += title.get(i);
                    titleString +=",";
                    markString += "?,";
                }

                titleString+= title.get(i);
                markString += "?";

                //System.out.println("Title String: "+titleString);
                //System.out.println("Mark String: "+markString);


                INSERT="insert into "+ TABLE_NAME + "("+titleString+")"+ "values" +"("+markString+")";
                System.out.println("Insert statement: "+INSERT);
                //System.out.println("Array size iiiiii::: "+array_vals.size());
                //this.insertStmt = this.myDataBase.compileStatement(INSERT);
                int s=0;

                while(s<array_vals.size()){

                System.out.println("Size of array1"+array_vals.size());
                        //System.out.println("Size of array"+title.size());
                int j=1;
                this.insertStmt = this.myDataBase.compileStatement(INSERT);
                for(int k =0;k< title.size();k++)
                {

                    //System.out.println("Value of column "+title+" is "+array_vals.get(k+s));
                    //System.out.println("PRINT S:"+array_vals.get(k+s));
                    System.out.println("BindString: insertStmt.bindString("+j+","+ array_vals.get(k+s)+")");
                    insertStmt.bindString(j, array_vals.get(k+s));



                    j++;
                }

                s+=title.size();

                }
                insertStmt.executeInsert();
            }
```